# In the QFT Lagrangian, what does the adjoint of $\psi$ represent, physically?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, antimatter

In the EM Lagrangian, the QCD Lagrangian, and the charged and neutral weak current Lagrangian, there is always a $\psi$ term and its adjoint $\bar{\psi}$.

The $\psi$ term can represent a Dirac spinor for EM, or a Dirac spinor $\otimes$ color space for QCD. AFAIK, it represents just a Dirac spinor for the weak currents as well.

My question is, what does the adjoint of $\psi$ represent, physically?

Does it represent an anti-particle, a particle creation operator, or something else?

Comment: What kind of field is $\psi$? Is it a complex scalar field? A Dirac spinor field? A Majorana spinor field? etc.

Comment: @probably_someone - either a spinor (for EM), or a spinor+color combo for QCD. As far as I can tell, for the _weak_ force (**not** electroweak), it would be just a spinor?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly - the EM Lagrangian, the QCD Lagrangian, and the charged and neutral weak current Lagrangian.

Comment: @ZenFox42 Saying "spinor" is not enough. It is not currently known whether neutrinos are represented as Dirac spinors or Majorana spinors. In the latter case, neutrinos are their own antiparticle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field operator annihilates a particle, or creates an antiparticle. The adjoint does the opposite, it creates a particle or annihilates an antiparticle.

Comment: Charles - so, just to be very clear, **every** instance of psi and the adjoint of psi in the EM Lagrangian, the QCD Lagrangian, and the charged and neutral weak current Lagrangian all act in the manner you describe?

Comment: Yes, this is imposed by mathematical structure. The only "exception" is if the particle is its own antiparticle, as for the photon, but that can be regarded as a special case of the same thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was really helpful!

Answer (score -2):

It has largelly the same meaning as the adjoint wave function in the usual QM. $\psi$ is a complex function, and one can write two equations for both real and imaginary parts of $\psi$, or equivalently two equations for $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't tell me anything about what they represent _physically_.

Comment: Then learn QM, please.

Comment: That was un-called for, and rude.  My question specifically asked for a physical representation, and your answer said only that psi was complex, and that it could be represented by two mathematical things, it said nothing about what it represents physically (unlike Charles' answer, which was spot-on).